# Exit app without using navigator.app.exitApp() - Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I don't want to use phonegap.js rather I've written an app using only jquery and stuff.
Previously I used the following line to exit the app.

```
navigator.app.exitApp()
```

Now it's not working when **I decided not to use phonegap.js** is my script. Is there any way to exit the phonegap app without using this. I've searched many forums but they mainly recommend this line of code and few others which also work only with phonegap js.

**Can I exit the app using only javascript or jquery?**